# Converting a sorting program from C to Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips32

I have to convert a sorting program which is written in C to assembly (Mips 32). I tried to do so but I doesn't work.

Here is the C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tab[10] = {3, 33, 49, 4, 23, 12, 46, 21, 48, 2};

void display(int * tab, int size) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d", tab[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void swap(int * tab, int i, int j) 
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = tab[i];
    tab[i] = tab[j];
    tab[j] = tmp;
}

void sort(int * tab, int size) 
{
    int valmax;
    int i, imax;

    if (size < 2) 
    {
        return;
    }

    valmax = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if (tab[i] > valmax) 
        {
            valmax = tab[i];
            imax = i;
        }
    }
    swap(tab, imax, size - 1);
    sort(tab, size - 1);
}

int main(void) 
{
    int size;
    size = 10;
    display(tab, size);
    sort(tab, size);
    display(tab, size);
    return 0;
}
```

And what I've already written :

```
.data
tab: .word 3,33,49,4,23,12,46,21,48,2
return: .asciiz "\n"
str: .asciiz "-----------\n"

.text
#--main--#
#---#
main:
addiu $29, $29, -16
sw $31, 12($29)

#---#
la $4, str
ori $2, $0, 4
syscall

la $4, tab #tab[]
ori $5, $0, 10 #size

jal display
jal sort

la $4, return
ori $2, $0, 4
syscall

la $4, tab #tab[]

jal display

ori $2, $0, 10
syscall

#---#
lw $31, 12($29)
addiu $29, $29, 16
jr $31



##display(int tab[], int size)##
#---#
display:
addiu $29, $29, -8
sw $31, 4($29)
sw $4, 8($29)
sw $5, 12($29)

#---#
li $8, 0
sw $8, 0($29) #i
loop1:
lw $5, 12($29)
beq $5, $8, endloop1
  lw $4, 8($29)
  sll $8, $8, 2 #i *= 4
  addu $8, $8, $4

  lw $4,($8)
  ori $2, $0, 1
  syscall

  la $4, return
  ori $2, $0, 4
  syscall

  lw $8, 0($29)
  addi $8, $8, 1
  sw $8, 0($29)
  j loop1

endloop1:

#---#
lw $31, 4($29)
lw $4, 8($29)
lw $5, 12($29)
addiu $29, $29, 8
jr $31



##swap(int tab[], int i, int j)##
#---#
swap:
addiu $29, $29, -8
sw $31, 4($29)
sw $4, 8($29)
sw $5, 12($29)
sw $6, 16($29)

#---#
sll $8, $5, 2 #i*4
add $8, $4, $8 #@tab[i]
lw $9, ($8) #tab[î]
sll $10, $6,  2 #j*4
add $10, $4, $10 #@tab[j]
lw $11, ($10) #tab[j]
sw $9, ($10)
sw $11, ($8)


#---#
lw $31, 4($29)
addiu $29, $29, 8
jr $31



##sort(int tab[], int size)##
#---#
sort:
addiu $29, $29, -36
sw $31, 32($29)
sw $16,  28($29)
sw $17, 24($29)
sw $18, 20($29)
sw $19, 16($29)
sw $4, 36($29)
sw $5, 40($29)
sw $6, 44($29)

#---#
slti $11, $5, 2
bne $11, $0, endif1

ori $17, $0, 0 #i

loop2:
beq $17, $5, endloop2

  sll $8, $17, 2 #4*i
  add $8, $4, $8 #@tab[i]
  lw $18,($8) #tab[i]

  ori $16, $0, 0 #valmax

  slt $11, $16, $18
  bne $11, $0, endif2

  ori $16, $18, 0
  ori $19, $17, 0 #imax

  endif2:
  addi $17, $17, 1
  j loop2

endloop2:
#swap+recursion
addi $6, $5, -1 #size-1
ori $5, $19, 0 #imax
jal swap

ori $5, $6, 0 #size-1
jal tri

#---#
endif1:
lw $31, 32($29)
lw $16, 28($29)
lw $17, 24($29)
lw $18, 20($29)
lw $19, 16($29)
lw $4, 36($29)
lw $5, 40($29)
lw $6, 44($29)
addiu $29, $29, 36
jr $31
```

But it doesn't work : the array is not correctly sorted. I guess that the problem is in the recursion, but I've not found. Could you help me to fix it please ?

Thanks :)
xDra

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through the program using a debugger? What have you found out while doing so?

Comment: Perhaps you could add more comments?  Not only would that make the code easier for the rest of us to read, but having to explain, line-by-line, what the code is doing can sometimes help you find the answer yourself.  And any time you hit a line where you can't quite describe what it does?  That's the line that's broken.

Answer (score 0):

For reference you can try compiling your program and inspecting the generated assembly to see what the flow looks like.
There are even online compilers these days that are handy for this kind of experimentation. Have a look at https://godbolt.org/ for example.